Excel Power Query syntax issue transform multiple columns of records
After many iterations I am progressing with the error messages, however, here I am running out of ideas.
I want to change several columns of a record, if the record fulfills a condition. If I do the operation for all records without checking a condition, it runs fine.
Statement without condition and no error
#"Adjustment" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"NewClmns",
   (r) = >Record.TransformFields(r, List.Transform(DateRange, 
      (c) => {c, each _ * #"DownrateFactor"} ) ) )),

Statement with condition and error value of type "TransformOperations" expected
#"Adjustment" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"NewClmns",
    (r) = >Record.TransformFields(r, 
       if r[#"Programname.2"] = "Qualified" then
          List.Transform( DateRange, 
             (c) => {c, each _ * 0.9}) 
       else Record.ToList(r) ) )),
   

This appears to come from the else statement, at least this is where I corrected the previous error (else r because r is a record and not a list)
=========================
Example
| Programmname.2 | 01012024 | 01022024 | 01032024 | 01042024 |
|----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| abc            | 1        | 1        | 1        | 1        |
| Qualified      | 1        | 1        | 1        | 1        |
| abc            | 1        | 1        | 1        | 1        |

shall become
| Programmname.2 | 01012024 | 01022024 | 01032024 | 01042024 |
|----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| abc            | 1        | 1        | 1        | 1        |
| Qualified      | 0.9      | 0.9      | 0.9      | 0.9      |
| abc            | 1        | 1        | 1        | 1        |

with
#"DateRange"  = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"PrevStep"),1),


It can probably be done. But without data, I cannot reproduce your problem. Please edit your question to post sample data as text, perhaps using this Markdown Tables Generator. And then also post at least a screenshot of your expected results from that data, and inform of any logic needed to get from the sample data to the expected outcome.

Thanks, I added an example. As I stated in the comment to the answer below, I have a workaround, however, was hoping for a more lean and elegant solution to the else statement

For what you show, it is relatively simple to use the Table.ReplaceValue function:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Programmname.2", type text}, {"01012024", Int64.Type}, {"01022024", Int64.Type}, 
        {"01032024", Int64.Type}, {"01042024", Int64.Type}}),
    
    #"Replace Qualified" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Changed Type",
        each [Programmname.2],
        0.9,
        (x,y,z)as nullable number=>if y = "Qualified" then x*z else x,
        List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"))
    )
in
    #"Replace Qualified"


Note: To understand the assignments, see the MS Help Page for this function. But, in terms of the function arguments ColumnsToSearch => x, OldValue=>y, NewValue=>z. Of course, we could rewrite it as below to name those arguments. Might make it more clear:
#"Replace Qualified" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Changed Type",
        each [Programmname.2] = "Qualified",
        0.9,
        (columnsToSearch, isQualified, Factor) as nullable number=> if isQualified then columnsToSearch * Factor else columnsToSearch,
        List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")))


Great, however, could you explain this a bit. Table.ReplaceValue(table as table, oldValue as any, newValue as any, replacer as function, columnsToSearch as list) as table, so you have the non-changed column as oldValue, 0.9 as newValue and (x,y,z) where I do not understand the assignment to any values. replacer and columnsToSearch I do understand. But no idea how you got to the previous statements

@w461 See my added note to my answer for an explanation of x,y,z. You can also check  Example 4 of the MS Help file for Table.ReplaceValue

I understood what x,y,z means. I was just wondering how Excel knows...

@w461 Excel has nothing to do with the interpretation of those parameters. This is Power Query and the language is M. The interpretation of three parameters is just how the function was designed.

I think the issue here is that you're using Record.ToList(r) in the else branch, which is incorrect because Record.TransformFields expects a list of transform operations
Try:
#"Adjustment" = Table.FromRecords(
    Table.TransformRows(#"NewClmns",
        (r) => Record.TransformFields(r,
            if r[#"Programname.2"] = "Qualified" then
                List.Transform(DateRange, (c) => {c, each _ * 0.9})
            else
                List.Transform(DateRange, (c) => {c, each _})  // No transformation, returns the original value
        )
    )
),


Thanks, this is what I used for the meantime. However, I thought there would be solution without having to process the (many) columns of every record in the table. So the minimum I can do is pick a single column and do some transformation (assign its value to itself)
